# Method of array or sequence of ui-views with Angular UI-Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application where certain sections used to be a series of routes in a nested ui-view.

In other words:

```
feedback.html--
              |--feedback-alerts.html
              |--feedback-progress.html
```

And so on, maybe 5-6 pages per section like this. On the main page was a sub-nav menu and a ui-view to hold the views as clicked in the menu.  It works fine.

Problem is, now my client would prefer to see ALL these subdocuments on the one page, and simply have the sub-menu links scroll down to each sub-section as clicked!

I would rather keep these templates separate.  I realize I can do `ng-include`s, and I might still, but I was wondering if there was some way to have the all-on-one-page experience with the views I have...

Here's my routes, with a few redundant ones removed.

```
  (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.ds.feedback').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('feedback', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/feedback',
      templateUrl: 'modules/feedback/templates/feedback.html',
      controller: 'FeedbackController as feedback',
      data: {
        pageTitle: 'feedback',
        access: 'public',
        bodyClass: 'feedback'
      }
    })

    .state('feedback.alerts', {
      url: '/alerts',
      templateUrl: 'modules/feedback/templates/feedback-alerts.html',
      controller: 'AlertsController as alerts'
    })

    .state('feedback.headermessage', {
      url: '/headermessage',
      templateUrl: 'modules/feedback/templates/feedback-header-message.html',
      controller: 'HeaderMessageController as message'
    });

  });

})();
```

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. If the views need to be combined what is the specific problem? Seems like you already answered your own question

Comment: Well, I can ditch the view entirely and put 6 pages' worth of HTML on the one page.  I was trying to brainstorm a way to keep them as 6 separate views.  It's probably a silly idea.